# Passing a Vector of Pointers c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector

Long time reader first time poster, be kind.

Working on an assignment and I am thoroughly stuck.
I have a class that holds a double variable. We are instructed to parse a file and sort the double values into a vector that "should hold pointers to the Double class" where we then write a function that takes "should take a vector of pointers to the Double class" and prints the vector to a file.

I am aware that simply passing the vector by reference would be preferable in a real world application as naked pointers are prone to memory leaks, but that is not what this assignment is asking for.

Below is the code I am working with. The issue seems to be in my function call and I have no idea how to resolve it. I am only in a level 2 class so please pardon my obvious errors.

> **Error** C2665 'writeNumbers': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

**The prototype that I am working with is below:**

`void writeNumbers(const vector<double*> &dNumbers);`

**the call in question is:**

`writeNumbers(dNumbers);` (I have also tried `*dNumbers` and `&dNumbers`)

**and the function definition:**

```
   void writeNumbers(const vector<double*> &dNumbers) {
          ofstream outfile("Double.txt");
          int size = dNumbers.size();
          for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
          {
                 outfile << *dNumbers[i] << endl;
          }

   }
```

Comment: Can you show how you call the function?

Comment: the call in question is:

writeNumbers(dNumbers); (I have also tried *dNumbers and &dNumbers)

Comment: How is `dNumbers` declared?

Comment: If you have a vector of pointers to single `double` values, why have pointers in the first place? What is the use case? What problem are you trying to solve by having plain and raw pointers in a vector?

Comment: As for your error, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and show ***all*** the output from the compiler, complete and unedited (it often includes hints or informational notes that can help understand the error).

Comment: Dag Nabbit, I just saw that that the argument is lowercase double and my class is Double. I think that may solve the issue. I'll have to check that when I get home. I must have been too tired to code last night. @JoachimPileborg the use is that it is supposed to be a vector of pointers to our class, not primitive doubles. That is where my mistake is. 

The dNumbers is declared vector<Double*> dNumbers;

That was all of the output from the compiler minus the file path.